# Why does select theme in Android Studio cause my layout become different

Tags: android, material-design

i using android studio to start develop apps, but i have some question about "Select Theme" in android studio. First, i noticed i select "NoActionBar" option, the layout will be like
[image]

The statusbar has no color, but after when i change to "AppTheme", the layout became
[image]

I had double check the code in styles.xml, but there are no changes. I really can't figure out about this. Can anyone explain this to me? Thank in advance.

**I have figured out actually select theme only the preview, it doesn't change my XML layout.

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is. This setting however is just for the preview, it has no effect what so ever on the deployed app. To change the theme of your app you have to change it in the AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag (e.g. "android:theme="@style/AppTheme").

Comment: The setting is just for preview? It did not affect when run the apps in phone?

Comment: Yes. The setting you highlighted in the first picture is just for the preview.

Comment: I think i got it, the affect for layout is need to changing the code but not the setting. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. There is usually a "AppTheme" in the styles.xml, thats where you should adapt your style. Then check that this seem is set as the theme of your application in the AndroidManifest.xml. In the preview just select "AppTheme" also, to preview as it will look like.

Comment: Thank you very much for make it clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you will find this in styles.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In your layout, two things are happening here
 1. Your layout have a toolbar in its xml. So toolbar always showing.
 2. the above pic will give you an idea about how the material theme isapplying with colors.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is really help me, but i think i have figure out my question. Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

check the colorPrimary and the colorPrimaryDark in your color.xml file

Comment: I have put in the color code in both colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark. Thank for your reply.